# How to combine minutes to a timeblock

Tags: php, time, grouping

On the background runs a script that checks if someone is available. This script then inserts a value in the database. I have no control over this script. Output is as follows:

```
12:01:00
12:02:00
12:03:00
12:10:00
12:11:00
12:12:00
12:13:00
12:14:00
12:15:00
```

etc

Now I need to group this data using PHP so I will end up with the first and last data of the consecutive rows. So in this case the data I need would be:

```
12:01:00
12:03:00
12:10:00
12:15:00
```

I've searched this forum and Google, but perhaps my English is not good enough to find the answer. I've tried various ideas (like comparing the time to the previous time, but everytime I hit unexpected or not working results).

Comment: Your question need some more clarity on Grouping part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read a time string and set it to the start and the end of a time period.
2. Read the next time string.
3. Calculate the difference of time strings and if it is less than 00:01:00 extend the time period. If it is more than 1 minute, print the time period and start a new time period. Go to 2.

When you use mtkime() and date(), you should call

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Following is a code sample. Data is stored in an array as strings.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$arr = array(
    '12:01:00',
    '12:02:00',
    '12:03:00',
    '12:10:00',
    '12:11:00',
    '12:12:00',
    '12:13:00',
    '12:14:00',
    '12:15:00'
);

// Start of code sample
$firsttime = true;
$start_time = '';
$end_time = '';
foreach ($arr as $time) {
    if ($firsttime === true) {  // start of a new time range
        // above test can be changed to $start_time === '' && $end_time === ''
        $firsttime = false;
        $start_time = $time;
        $end_time = $time;
    } else {
        $diff = diff_time($end_time, $time);
        // insert error check here
        if ($diff <= '00:01:00') {  // consecutive
            $end_time = $time;  // update end of the time range
        } else {    // end of the time range
            echo $start_time, '<br />';
            echo $end_time, '<br />';
            $start_time = $time;
            $end_time = $time;
        }
    }
}
if ($start_time !== '' && $end_time !== '') {
    echo $start_time, '<br />';
    echo $end_time, '<br />';
}
echo 'End<hr />';

function diff_time($from_time, $to_time) {
    if (preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/', $from_time, $captured)) {
        $from = mktime($captured[1], $captured[2], $captured[3], 1, 1, 2000);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/', $to_time, $captured)) {
        $to = mktime($captured[1], $captured[2], $captured[3], 1, 1, 2000);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if ($from > $to) {
        return date('-H:i:s', $from - $to);
    } else {
        return date('H:i:s', $to - $from);
    }
```